# Day and dynamic Date in a column header

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I want to create a timesheet table in which the column header contains Day and dynamically changing date. For example, if a user selects 2/1/2015 as the Start date that is Sunday, I want to show columns with header Sunday 1/2/2015, Monday 2/2/2015.

I have used the following code :

```
<apex:column headerValue="Monday" style="width:50px;" > 
 <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}"> 
  <apex:param value="{!timesheet.EnterDate__c +1}" /> 
 </apex:outputText> 
 <apex:inputField value="{!t.Monday__c}" style="width:50px;"/> 
</apex:column>
```

Comment: Can you add what you've tried to your question?

Comment: Thanks for including your current code, but that doesn't explain what output it gives you (why it's wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that outputText is properly formatted, so I think what you're going for is to have that in the Column header, correct? If that's the case, then try this:

```
<apex:column width="50px" >
    <apex:facet name="header" >
        <apex:outputText value="Monday {0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}"> 
            <apex:param value="{!timesheet.EnterDate__c +1}" /> 
        </apex:outputText>
    </apex:facet>
    <apex:inputField value="{!t.Monday__c}" style="width:50px;"/> 
</apex:column>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem. Upvote please :)